# Footer Centering Help

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple question I believe. I have a footer.php that I put on my main page and all subpages (to make it easier so I can change the footer in one location). And I am trying to make it so the footer remains at the center of the fixed-width no matter what size the browser window is. For example, I want my pages to be 950px width and the footer always be in the center, so that even when I resize the browser to as small as it goes, it simply COVERS the footer, rather then moving it with the resized window. Much like apple.coms footer.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Well described question for a newbie. +1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your markup:

```
<div id="footer-container">
    <div id="footer">
        Footer stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
#footer-container {
    /* centering for IE */
    text-align: center;
}
#footer {
    width: 950px;
    /* undo text-align on container */
    text-align: left;
    /* centering for other browsers */
    margin: auto;
}
```

---

Edit: I was putting this comment on some of the other solutions, but deleted them because I didn't want to copy/paste on all of them.  Just please be aware that `margin: auto` doesn't work in older versions of IE, so if you want to have the footer aligned in the middle, you'll need to do some nesting, like I have in this one.

Comment: Fair warning it's only IE6 that doesn't support that, every time you support IE6 God kills a puppy

Comment: That may be true, but every time I don't support IE6, my boss kills two puppies.  :\

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the quick tips. Worked PERFECTLY. Im curious, how would one go about centering an image instead of just text under this same context?

Comment: Centering an image would be done about the same.  Use a container with `text-align: center;`, and then apply `margin: auto;` to the image.  The `text-align: left;` is obviously unnecessary on the image, and setting the `width` is optional.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to set the `width` of your footer and then give it a `margin:0 auto` where `0` stands for the top and bottom margins and `auto` is for the left and right.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the `width: 950px`, and `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`.

With the left/right margins at `auto`, the `<div>` will be centered.  Once the size of the browser gets down to the point where scrolling is needed, the browser will not shrink your `<div>`, it will just require left/right scrolling, which is needed for your content anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve it with a little bit of CSS:

html & php:

```
<div id="footer">
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)